# IntelliJ plugin, reuse system form

Tags: swing, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin

I am developing small plugin for setting up background image (I know they are exist, but i would like to create more flexible).

All existed plugin reuse existed functionality of IDEA. (Appearance -> Background Image).  I would like to integrate that system form into my setting page.

So it would be great if I can add system form somewhere below my own form. If not so can I just invoke it?

[image: My developing page]

Answer (score 0):

After digging system functionality I found a waн to show System Dialog with Image settings.

I found a Way how to display System Pop Up window!

```
String lastIdeImage = properties.getValue(IdeBackgroundUtil.EDITOR_PROP, "");
BackgroundImageDialog dialog = new BackgroundImageDialog(activeProject, lastIdeImage);
dialog.showAndGet();
```

So.. Now I See that this is a dialog and this is not os easy to get UI from there!